# Is it gas efficient to store the msg.sender in a local var?

Tags: contract-design, gas

Suppose I have a function that refers to `msg.sender` many times:

```
function foo() external {
  doSomething(msg.sender);
  
  // ...
  
  doSomethingElse(msg.sender)
 
  // ...

  emit LogSomething(msg.sender);
}
```

Would it be more efficient if I stored `msg.sender` in a local variable, like so?

```
function foo() external {
  address msgSender = msg.sender;

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is easy enough to test.

I created the following extra smart contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.8.0;

contract Test {
    function novar() public {
        require(msg.sender != address(0));
        require(msg.sender != address(0));
        require(msg.sender != address(0));
        require(msg.sender != address(0));
    }
    function yesvar() public {
        address s = msg.sender;
        require(s != address(0));
        require(s != address(0));
        require(s != address(0));
        require(s != address(0));
    }
}
```

With the given setup, calling `novar` costs 21564 and `yesvar` is 21558. So it seems it is cheaper to use the variable. I'm really not sure why.

But things get a bit more interesting if we add the number of repetitions. If both functions have 8 repetitions, the difference is only 2 gas. If both have 16 repetitions, the `novar` version is already cheaper by 6 gas.

So, the end result is: **it depends**.

Comment: actually the gas cost of a function call is dependent on the function signature also and not just the content. but calling msg.sender is cheaper then storing it in a local variable so better to access it directly.